# define class methods and class variables in R5 reference class

Tags: oop, r, reference-class

I want to know the correct way to define the class methods and class variable in R5 reference class.

Here is an example:

```
> # define R5 class XX
> # member variable: ma
> # member method: mfa
> XX <- setRefClass("XX",
+   fields = list(ma = "character"),
+   methods = list(
+     mfa = function() return(paste(ma, "*"))
+     ))
> 
> XX
Generator object for class "XX":

Class fields:

Name:         ma
Class: character

 Class Methods:  
    "callSuper", "copy", "export", "field", "getClass", "getRefClass", "import", "initFields", 
"mfa"


 Reference Superclasses:  
    "envRefClass"

> # create an instance of XX
> x <- XX$new(ma="ma")
> 
> # call member method refering to the member variable.
> x$mfa()
[1] "ma *"
> 
> # here, I define *class* variable
> XX$cc <- "cc"

> # contents of XX
> ls(XX)
[1] "cc"        "className" "def"       "methods"   "new"      

> # here, I define member method referring to the class var.
> XX$methods(mfc = function() {
+   return(XX$cc)
+ })

> # it does work.
> x$mfc()
[1] "cc"
```

The `XX$cc <- "cc"` behaves as if the `cc` is class variable of XX, but I'm not sure if this is a correct way. 
For example, XX$def <- "hoge" can break the XX class generator.

So, I want to know if there is a standard way to define class variable and methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent of class methods/variables in the reference object framework.

Comment: @hadley thanks. then, do you think there is any reason not to implement class methods/variables in R5 class?

Comment: I just don't think they have any role.  Can you provide an example of what you need class variables/methods for?

Comment: Perhaps there would never be the case where the class var/methods are absolutely necessary. As I'm familiar with the OOP style of C++ where class var/methods are supported, so I just wondered if the R5 system supports them, and if not, why. But anyway, there are many ways to do similar thing as @goodside also says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding a "standard" for class variables, no such standard exists. Reference classes are a new feature to R, and to the extent that some aspect of OO isn't documented in the [official documentation on reference classes](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/getRefClass), it's safe to assume that it hasn't yet been standardized.

As for whether such a standard might appear, I doubt it. Class variables are really just volatile globals in a pseudo-namespace, and relying on external state generally isn't the R way of doing things. The existence of reference classes is already a pretty big concession against this to improve performance.

But, as you noted, what you've done does work. R is a language for consenting adults, and it won't try to stop you from introducing messiness at your own risk.